# Render dozens of quotes, arranged so that they fill page(s)

Tags: quotation

(Background:
I have a csv file with three columns: quote, context, name. I am able to use Python Jinja templating to insert them in a latex document using foreach. The csv has 120+ rows)

How do I arrange so many quotes on one or two pages with \LaTeX (XeLaTex) over let's say two pages? I thought of using parbox (https://golatex.de/wiki/%5Cparbox), but maybe anyone has a better idea where it doesn't look that "strict" (as in left-center-right arranged)

Comment: Using a liberate share of `\vfill`?

Comment: Actually, that's good idea, thank you :)